# I get the following errors when I use sudo apt-get update

Tags: software-sources

`W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy/Release` 
`Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-1386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`

I think need to edit this from  `main/binary-1386/Packages` to `main/binary-i386/Packages`.

I'm new to Ubuntu so could someone give me a step by step guide to finding and altering this entry?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you gave us more information about what version you're using, etc.

Answering your question on how to modify the package sources, you might want to use the "software and updates" then select the "Other software" tab, and finally select the line that causes trouble and click on edit.